# Как использовать str.replace в js для input

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

есть инпут в который нужно разрешить вводить только определенные символы формата ЫЫ-111/1111111;
Пытаюсь использовать replace
подобрал регулярку под мои условия а как ее  применить не пойму
/([А-Я]{2}-[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{7})/ig
Не могу заставить работать даже простую

```
 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState()       
 <input value={inputValue}
      onChange={(event) => {
          const value = event.target.value;                   
          setInputValue(value.replace(/[^А-Я]{2}/ig, '');)
      }}
  />
```

Ввод разрешает только большим русским буквам, но количество не ограничивает. Подскажите как правильно делать replace. Сейчас пытаюсь сделать несколькими replace, но пока что тоже безуспешно.

Answer (score 0):

а зачем repalce если надо проверять на совпадение?

как вариант так

```
export const App = () => {
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

   const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let isCorrect =(/\d/ig).test(value)
    if(isCorrect){
      console.log(isCorrect)
      return
    }      
    setInputValue((prev) => value)
   }     
 
  return (
    <input value={inputValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
  />
  )
```

Comment: Что-бы не давать вводить недопустимые варианты

Comment: @Ivan а тогда зачем зря вызывать setState? надо делать как я если значение неккоректное нечего не делать, если же надо как то реогировать то можно использовать другой state

Comment: setState все равно вызывать что-бы был контролируемый input